# Converting a full colour vector to a single outline vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector

Im looking to convert a full colour vector image into pretty much a line drawing with no fill. I use illustrator CS6. I have tried the Edit> Edit Colours> Recolour Artwork. However, when I'm done it still fills in the drawings where a colours were filled previously. deleting the colours inside isnt possible as the vector image was created through a live trace.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: kindly upload a sample .eps or .ai file.So that we an see it and help you in better way.

Answer (score 2):

- Select all
- Set fill to White
- Stroke to black

This is essentially line art. Note white fills don't print.

If you *really* want to remove the white, do the above then.....

- Select all
- `Object > Expand`
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) and click 1 white shape
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

You are left with only black shapes making up the outline of the objects.

Comment: I have always needed this object expand feature in all svg icons but not available in any other tools except illustrator. Is there any other online tool for converting fill to outlines?